# Other user overwrote my latest commit somehow I cant find it in history?

Tags: git, history

I updated a file with several new lines of code 2 days ago, but after my latest pull those changes are completely gone and a git log -p has no history of such changes / reverts...

Is there a way to see how this occurred?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding out what happened depends on what git hosting you're using.  Services such as github and bitbucket will keep track of who pushes what, and display this information in a very readable way (just *how* it's displayed depends on your hosting provider).  Otherwise, you can try to use the [reflog on the server](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/keeping-log-of-branch-updates-on-git/) to find out what happened.  (Requires some configuration though so it might just be useful for in the future).

As far as recovering your work though, [check your local reflog](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) to find your lost commits.

**EDIT** I should mention, it's very hard for you to lose commits this way.  The other user would have had to force a push to the remote repository because git would otherwise warn them and fail to push. And even if they did that, you would have been warned if you attempted to pull from the repository after this had happened.  I bring all this up, because if you did not get warned, you probably never had those commits you thought you had on that branch in the first place